# Why I can't do cpu-profiling when the process blocking by String(str).replace(some_regexp, '') in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

For Example，blow function `testReplace` will blocking the Node.js process:

```
function testReplace() {
    let str = '<br/>                                                        早餐后自由活动，于指定时间集合自行办理退房手续。';
    str += '<br/>                                      <br/>                                        <br/>                                    <br/>';
    str += '                                    <br/>                                                                                                                        <br/>';
    str += '                                                <br/>                                                                                                            <br/>';
    str += '                                                                                                                    根据船班时间，自行前往暹粒机场，返回中国。<br/>';
    str += '如需送机服务，需增加280/每单。<br/>';

    let r = String(str).replace(/(^(\s*?<br[\s\/]*?>\*?)+|(\s*?<br[\s\/]*?>\s*?)+?$)/igm, '');
    console.log(str)
}
```

And I want to know where is the blocking function, so I use `v8-profiler` to do cpu-profiling when the process blocking, such as:

```
v8Profiler.startProfiling('easy_monitor', true);
setTimeout(() => {
    let profile = v8Profiler.stopProfiling('easy_monitor');
    profile.delete();
}, 5000);
```

but this always throw error:

```
Bus error: 10
```

How can I resolve this problem? If you can help me I'll really appreciate to you ：）

Comment: I prefer a GUI for profiling etc, so I use `node --inspect` and attach the chrome dev tools. Maybe give that a try.

Comment: My guess would be that your regular expression might suffer from [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).

Answer (score 0):

node --trace foo.js will provide you with the methid trace, as below:

```
  10:          new ~RegExp+23(this=0x167100086871 <JS RegExp>, 0x1667d2c3e3b9 <String[51]: (^(\s*?<br[\s\/]*?>\*?)+|(\s*?<br[\s\/]*?>\s*?)+?$)>, 0x1667d2c3e409 <String[3]: igm>) {
  11:           ~DoConstructRegExp+23(this=0x9d97d041b9 <undefined>, 0x167100086871 <JS RegExp>, 0x1667d2c3e3b9 <String[51]: (^(\s*?<br[\s\/]*?>\*?)+|(\s*?<br[\s\/]*?>\s*?)+?$)>, 0x1667d2c3e409 <String[3]: igm>) {
  12:            ~ToString+23(this=0x9d97d041b9 <undefined>, 0x1667d2c3e3b9 <String[51]: (^(\s*?<br[\s\/]*?>\*?)+|(\s*?<br[\s\/]*?>\s*?)+?$)>) {
  12:            } -> 0x1667d2c3e3b9 <String[51]: (^(\s*?<br[\s\/]*?>\*?)+|(\s*?<br[\s\/]*?>\s*?)+?$)>
  12:            ~ToString+23(this=0x9d97d041b9 <undefined>, 0x1667d2c3e409 <String[3]: igm>) {
  12:            } -> 0x1667d2c3e409 <String[3]: igm>
  11:           } -> 0x9d97d041b9 <undefined>
  10:          } -> 0x9d97d041b9 <undefined>
  10:          ~replace+36(this=0x167100086849 <String[715]\: <br/>                                                        \x65e9\x9910\x540e\x81ea\x7531\x6d3b\x52a8\xff0c\x4e8e\x6307\x5b9a\x65f6\x95f4\x96c6\x5408\x81ea\x884c\x529e\x7406\x9000\x623f\x624b\x7eed\x3002<br/>                                      <br/>                                        <br/>                                    <br/>                                    <br/>                                                                                                                        <br/>                                                <br/>                                                                                                            <br/>                                                                                                                    \x6839\x636e\x8239\x73ed\x65f6\x95f4\xff0c\x81ea\x884c\x524d\x5f80\x66b9\x7c92\x673a\x573a\xff0c\x8fd4\x56de\x4e2d\x56fd\x3002<br/>\x5982\x9700\x9001\x673a\x670d\x52a1\xff0c\x9700\x589e\x52a0280/\x6bcf\x5355\x3002<br/>>, 0x167100086911 <JS RegExp>, 0x9d97d04291 <String[0]: >) {
```

So clearly, your code is stuck at String.replace method.

```
  * frame #0: 0x00000af481b48e5b
    frame #1: 0x0000000100502574 node`v8::internal::NativeRegExpMacroAssembler::Match(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Code>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::String>, int*, int, int, v8::internal::Isolate*) + 244
    frame #2: 0x0000000100436841 node`v8::internal::RegExpImpl::IrregexpExecRaw(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSRegExp>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::String>, int, int*, int) + 481
    frame #3: 0x0000000100545e72 node`v8::internal::Runtime_StringReplaceGlobalRegExpWithString(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) + 4930
    frame #4: 0x00000af481a0963b
    frame #5: 0x00000af481b14d09
    frame #6: 0x00000af481b47d16
    frame #7: 0x00000af481b474a4
    frame #8: 0x00000af481a345e7
    frame #9: 0x00000af481b46e69
    frame #10: 0x00000af481b3f80b
    frame #11: 0x00000af481b3c43b
    frame #12: 0x00000af481b31a84
    frame #13: 0x00000af481b31486
    frame #14: 0x00000af481a3b7fa
    frame #15: 0x00000af481a38c72
    frame #16: 0x00000af481a318fd
    frame #17: 0x00000af481a15b62
    frame #18: 0x00000001002dad88 node`v8::internal::Invoke(bool, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSFunction>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, int, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>*) + 728
    frame #19: 0x0000000100166d84 node`v8::Function::Call(v8::Local<v8::Context>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*) + 276
    frame #20: 0x0000000100666d0a node`node::LoadEnvironment(node::Environment*) + 486
    frame #21: 0x000000010066819d node`node::Start(int, char**) + 508
    frame #22: 0x0000000100000d34 node`start + 52
```

Internally, it is stuck in the regular expression parser in the v8 native code.

It would be worthwhile to raise a bug with v8, if you are sure about the valid characters in the input, and the expression.

Hope this helps.